New Mersenne Primes Found -- Need help with Lucas-Lehmer Tests Please.
I wrote some Python3 code last night to work on this problem for fun and seemingly stumbled upon two new Mersenne Primes. I'm still learning so I don't quite understand how to format the Lucas-Lehmer Test, and could use some help if you've got time.
They are as follows:
$2^{2147483647}-1$, and $2^{2305843009213693951}-1$
According to WolframAlpha they're both Mersenne Primes.
I tried to start up GIMPS but my computer can't handle the heat.
Thanks for your time.



What you asked WolframAlpha is not what you've asked us about...

You found numbers that are Mersenne primes , let us call such a number $M$. Why do you then think that $2^M-1$ is prime again ?

The mentioned test is the Lucas-Lehmer test , but the author does not actually search for a program to find them , instead had the impression that Wolfram Alpha approved the mentioned huge numbers to be prime which is not the case.

Sorry for the confusion. I'm new. I'm looking to verify if these are Mersenne Primes based on what I looked up online, which what I've learned is using the Lucas-Fehrer test. I can ask WolframAlpha if they're both primes and they return that they are, but I don't know how to check if they Mersenne primes with these numbers as their exponents. If there is a way to structure the WolframAlpha questions properly so that it can determine if they are Mersenne primes based around their results it would be greatly appreciated.

@Jay Unless the mentioned huge numbers have a known prime factor, the first is extremely time consuming to test and the second utter hopeless with current technology.

Ask Wolfram whether the (small) numbers are Mersenne prime exponents. The answer is probably different then.

@Peter Thanks for the information. I'll try GIMPS again and see if I can set it up properly to work. Have a nice day.

Hello, $2^{2147483647}-1$ is composite, for example, one of the factor is $295257526626031$ See here https://www.mersenne.ca/exponent/2147483647

@Aurel-BG Nice , I guess the second has a known factor as well since it is a double mersenne number and those have intensively be studied.
